# How to compare strings and select one that matches

Tags: c#

I have an string like this:

```
string myString1 = "DOE, JOHN BE DOE, JANE"; //or
string myString2 = "DOE SMITH, JOHN BE DOE SMITH, JANE MARIE"; //or
string myString3 = "DOE, JOHN DOE, JANE"; //or
```

And a list of records called People, like this:

```
Name     | Surname      | Family
JOHNBE   | DOE          | JANE DOE
JOHNDA   | DOE          | JANE DOE
JOHNMU   | DOE          | JANE DOE
JANE     | SMITH        | MARIE SMITH
PAUL     | CARTER       | JOSEPH CARTER
...
```

I would like to select the first record when string is like myString1.

Also I need it to work out if this others situations happened as well.

I tried:

Put myString to a list:

```
var myList = {"DOE", "JOHN", "BE", "DOE", "JANE"}
```

and check if contains.

```
var test = People.Where(p => myList.Contains(p.Name));
```

I return zero as the Name doesn't exists.

Tried to pick first word after the "," like this:

```
var name = myString.Substring(item.ChildName.IndexOf(",") + 2).Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
```

Which returns "JOHN" then:

```
var test = People.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(name));
```

This returns the 3 records.

So here is the problem:

when I run the myString1 it returns 0, it should select the first record, the column Name has name and middle name together, so sometimes it will be together, sometimes separated in two words, eg.: JOHNBE | JOHN BE | JOHN. Does it make sense?

And myString will be surname comma firstname space middlename space surnameForFamily comma firstname for family space middlenameForFamily

Anyone have any idea how could do this search?

Comment: I don't understand what problem is occurring. You told me everything works.

Comment: Oh sorry, Ok, when I run the myString1 it returns 0, it should select the first record, the column Name has name and middle name together, so sometimes it will be together, sometimes separated in two words, eg.: JOHNBE | JOHN BE | JOHN. Does it make sense?

Comment: And myString will be surname comma firstname space middlename space surnameForFamily comma firstname for family space middlenameForFamily.

Comment: This sounds like you need a fuzzy search. Something like Lucene or Elastic Search would work really well here.

Comment: I would start by extracting the name, surname and family name from those `myString`s. Then compare those names against the record names. If a name contains spaces, then check against that name twice, once normally and once against the name without spaces. That should work, assuming there are no other edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using an equality comparer.

```
public class NameComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (y.Contains(x))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then during your query implement like so:

```
var myList = new List<string>() { "DOE", "JOHN", "BE", "DOE", "JANE" };          

var comp = new NameComparer();
var test = People.Where(x => myList.Contains(x.Name, comp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using part of Pieter suggestion.

Solution:

Started getting the first name from mystring1, eg: "JOHN", which is the only valid know part of string (first word after the first comma),

Then in People table I select everything that matches the word "JOHN", it returned 3 rows, stripped the word "JOHN" from the column name, and for last checked the column Name against myList, it returned the right row only. Tested on other cases that could appear in mystring1 and seems to work right.

Thanks Pieter for suggestion.